# How to write two select statements in xsl variable?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Currently I have  a xsl statement which whill lookup for ITNBR in database table and gives result.

```
<xsl:if test="$DB_PUBLISHEVENT_PLMITEMOUT/PLANTCODE='F'">
<xsl:variable name="varBOMExistsAsPartOnMapics" select="globalMethod:DBQuery($varConn,$_class,$_identifier,$_subject,concat('SELECT COUNT(ITNBR) FROM ITMRVA WHERE ',concat(' ITNBR=',$apos,$varCrossRefNoCompNumber,$apos)),$varConnection_ERP_Mapics,'false')" xmlns:globalMethod="java:com.adeptia.indigo.services.mapping.support.dbquery.MapperQueryExecutor"/>
```

Now I wanted to change this xsl to write two select statements with OR command. So now xsl statement will lookup for ITNBR in 2 tables with atleast itmnr existing in one table.

I tried writing or between the 2 xsl variable and by writing || between xsl variables.

```
<xsl:if test="$DB_PUBLISHEVENT_PLMITEMOUT/PLANTCODE='F'">
<xsl:variable name="varBOMExistsAsPartOnMapics" select="globalMethod:DBQuery($varConn,$_class,$_identifier,$_subject,concat('SELECT COUNT(ITNBR) FROM ITMRVA WHERE ',concat(' ITNBR=',$apos,$varCrossRefNoCompNumber,$apos)),$varConnection_ERP_Mapics,'false')" xmlns:globalMethod="java:com.adeptia.indigo.services.mapping.support.dbquery.MapperQueryExecutor"/>
```

I expect if PLANTCODE is F, then db lookup should check for ITMMNBR in 2 diff tables.

Comment: code:
<xsl:if test="$DB_PUBLISHEVENT_PLMITEMOUT/PLANTCODE='F'">
<xsl:variable name="varBOMExistsAsPartOnMapics" select="globalMethod:DBQuery($varConn,$_class,$_identifier,$_subject,concat('SELECT COUNT(ITNBR) FROM ITMRVA WHERE ',concat(' ITNBR=',$apos,$varCrossRefNoCompNumber,$apos)),$varConnection_ERP_Mapics,'false')" xmlns:globalMethod="java:com.adeptia.indigo.services.mapping.support.dbquery.MapperQueryExecutor"/>

Comment: [edit] your question and add your code there, not in a comment.

Comment: I have code in body, but not sure why it is not showing up. @kjhughes

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a [mcve].